# How to solved error: Inconsistent accessibility: constraint type 'IEntity' is less accessible than 'GenericRepository<T>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, interface, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an interface with its following methods (GetAll, GetById, CreateAsync ... etc) in diamond notation I tell you it is a repository of T, where T is a class, so you can change T for any model or entity that has

IGENERICREPOSITORY.CS:

```
 public interface  IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetAll();

        Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id);

        Task<T> CreateAsync(T entity);

        Task<T> UpdateAsync(T entity);

        Task DeleteAsync(T entity);

        Task<bool> ExistAsync(int id);
    }
```

But when implementing the interface, in a class called GenericRepository.cs it tells me an inconsistency error, I attach my GenericRepository.CS class

GENERICREPOSTITORY.CS:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
    {
        private readonly DataContext context;

        public GenericRepository(DataContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return this.context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await this.context.Set<T>()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
        }

        public async Task<T> CreateAsync(T entity)
        {
            await this.context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
            await SaveAllAsync();
            return entity;
        }

        public async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T entity)
        {
            this.context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
            await SaveAllAsync();
            return entity;
        }

        public async Task DeleteAsync(T entity)
        {
            this.context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
            await SaveAllAsync();
        }

        public async Task<bool> ExistAsync(int id)
        {
            return await this.context.Set<T>().AnyAsync(e => e.Id == id);

        }

        public async Task<bool> SaveAllAsync()
        {
            return await this.context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }
    }
```

The error is as follows:

> Inconsistent accessibility: constraint type 'IEntity' is less accessible than 'GenericRepository'

what am I doing wrong? Why can not I implement the GenericRepostory.cs class? I think I have all the uses and inheritances in a correct way, any help for me?

Comment: Most likely `IEntity` is not a public interface, it could be internal for instance. Can you show the declaration of that interface as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's cause type `IEntity` is declared with non public access modifier whereas `GenericRepository<T>` is declared `public`

Answer (score 1):

> Constraint type 'IEntity' is less accessible than
>   'GenericRepository<T>'

This means that `IEntity` does not have the same (or wider) accessibility than `GenericRepository<T>`. The compiler gives this error because it would lead to inconsistencies, e.g. how would you call your `UpdateAsync` if you can't even create a `IEntity` to pass to it?

To solve the issue, you can either make `IEntity` `public` or restrict the access to `GenericRepository<T>` to the same level as `IEntity` (for example `internal`if `IEntity` is marked as such), depending on your intended use case.